# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined" while connecting to mongodb using env variables

Tags: node.js, mongodb, environment-variables

I am fairly new to full-stack, I started learning and making a demo site using node, express, and MongoDB.
I was learning through youtube(WebDevSimplified).

i connected my project to my MongoDB using the uri. and was working fine. in the tutorial a new methord was said is:
1.install tool dotenv( `npm i --save-dev dotenv` ).
2.create a .env file and lode a field-( `DATABASE_URL= mongodb://localhost/db` )
3.check if the file is in production env.----

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    require('dotenv').parse()
}
```

4.for connecting to db use uri as.----

```
mongoose.connect( process.env.DATABASE_URL, {useNewUrlParser: true})
```

I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
at Object.parse (F:\MVC project\webdevSimplified\node_modules\dotenv\lib\main.js:42:7)
at Object.<anonymous> (F:\MVC project\webdevSimplified\server.js:2:23)
```

the next step is deploying in Heroku. for that I think I require to get this so please help me...

Answer (score 3):

try

**`require('dotenv').config()`**

Comment: Although this code has provided a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Comment: This still works today! .parse() did not work!